# Label does not update using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uilabel, avplayer

I'm trying to improve a GitHub project I forked (https://github.com/giacmarangoni/Swift-Radio-Pro/tree/xcode8).
After some fixes and changes everything seems to work good but suddenly I noticed a really strange behavior.
When I open "NowPlayingViewController" for the first time and station starts to stream, everything is working and AVPlayer delegate updates user interface as expected (songLabel, titleLabel and albumArtwork).
After that, without stopping radio streaming, I tried to go back to "StationsViewController" and immediately to reopen "NowPlayingViewController" using "Now playing" button.
At this point delegation is still active, streaming is going on, but when song changes all variables in this view controller are updated but I can't say the same for the user interface. I tried to debug and I noticed that labels are populated but not updated. UI updates in the main thread and `setNeedDisplay` didn't help.

**NowPlayingViewController**

AVPlayer setup:

```
func setUpPlayer(){
        radioPlayer = Player.radio
        radioPlayer.rate = 1
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(self.playerItemDidReachEnd),
            name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
            object: self.radioPlayer.currentItem
        )

    }
```

Here you can find `func onMetaData(_ metaData: [AVMetadataItem]?)`).

```
//*****************************************************************
// MARK: - AVPlayerItem Delegate (for metadata)
//*****************************************************************
extension NowPlayingViewController: CustomAVPlayerItemDelegate {
    func onMetaData(_ metaData: [AVMetadataItem]?) {
        if let metaDatas = metaData{
            startNowPlayingAnimation()
            let firstMeta: AVMetadataItem = metaDatas.first!
            let metaData = firstMeta.value as! String
            var stringParts = [String]()
            if metaData.range(of: " - ") != nil {
                stringParts = metaData.components(separatedBy: " - ")
            } else {
                stringParts = metaData.components(separatedBy: "-")
            }
            // Set artist & songvariables
            let currentSongName = track.title
            track.artist = stringParts[0].decodeAllChars()
            track.title = stringParts[0].decodeAllChars()
            if stringParts.count > 1 {
                track.title = stringParts[1].decodeAllChars()
            }                
            if track.artist == "" && track.title == "" {
                track.artist = currentStation.stationDesc
                track.title = currentStation.stationName
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if currentSongName != self.track.title {
                    if kDebugLog {
                        print("METADATA artist: \(self.track.artist) | title: \(self.track.title)")
                    }

                    // Update Labels
                    self.artistLabel.text = self.track.artist
                    self.songLabel.text = self.track.title
                    self.updateUserActivityState(self.userActivity!)
                    // songLabel animation
                    self.songLabel.animation = "zoomIn"
                    self.songLabel.duration = 1.5
                    self.songLabel.damping = 1
                    self.songLabel.animate()
                    // Update Stations Screen
                    self.delegate?.songMetaDataDidUpdate(self.track)
                    // Query API for album art
                    self.resetAlbumArtwork()
                    self.queryAlbumArt()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method is observed in "CustomAVPlayerItem" according to `timedMetaData` key path; It's fired every time AVPlayer metadatas change. This class is a subclass of AVPlayerItem:

```
import MediaPlayer
import Foundation

protocol CustomAVPlayerItemDelegate {
    func onMetaData(_ metaData:[AVMetadataItem]?)
}

//*****************************************************************
// Makes sure that observers are removed before deallocation
//*****************************************************************
class CustomAVPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem {

    var delegate : CustomAVPlayerItemDelegate?

    init(url URL:URL)
    {
        if kDebugLog {print("CustomAVPlayerItem.init")}
        super.init(asset: AVAsset(url: URL) , automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys:[])
        addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timedMetadata", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
    }

    deinit{        
        if kDebugLog {print("CustomAVPlayerItem.deinit")}
        removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timedMetadata")
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if let avpItem: AVPlayerItem = object as? AVPlayerItem {
            if keyPath == "timedMetadata" {                
                delegate?.onMetaData(avpItem.timedMetadata)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following is my AVPlayer:

```
import MediaPlayer

//*****************************************************************
// This is a singleton struct using Swift
//*****************************************************************
struct Player {
    static var radio = AVPlayer()
}
```

This is the segue function I use to open to "NowPlayingViewController".
 **StationsViewController**

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "NowPlaying" {

            self.title = ""
            firstTime = false

            let nowPlayingVC = segue.destination as! NowPlayingViewController
            nowPlayingVC.delegate = self

            if let indexPath = (sender as? IndexPath) {
                // User clicked on row, load/reset station
                if searchController.isActive {
                    currentStation = searchedStations[indexPath.row]
                } else {
                    currentStation = stations[indexPath.row]
                }
                nowPlayingVC.currentStation = currentStation
                nowPlayingVC.newStation = true

            } else {
                // User clicked on a now playing button
                if let currentTrack = currentTrack {
                    // Return to NowPlaying controller without reloading station
                    nowPlayingVC.track = currentTrack
                    nowPlayingVC.currentStation = currentStation
                    nowPlayingVC.newStation = false
                } else {
                    // Issue with track, reload station
                    nowPlayingVC.currentStation = currentStation
                    nowPlayingVC.newStation = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any code that ever calls `onMetaData`.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Why have you posted so much code here if only `onMetaData` is at issue?

Comment: More information provided. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Can you try to run the Label Updates also in the dipatch Main traililng closure?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Neo, I tried and It didn't work. I also tried to fire an alert in same place and as the label It fires only on the first time. After going back to previous controller and returning, It didn't work. Instead all variable such as track.artist or title are populate. Debugger print also correct text in label, but my view seems to be idle.

Comment: The obvious suggestion is that the view you are _seeing_ is not the view whose labels are being updated. That can happen, for example, if you create the view controller incorrectly.

Comment: "After that, without stopping radio streaming, I tried to go back to "StationsViewController" and immediately to reopen "NowPlayingViewController" using "Now playing" button." Clearly that's where the problem is. The "Now playing" button is not creating and incorporating the NowPlayingViewController correctly. Keep in mind that after you go back, to StationsViewController, your original NowPlayingViewController is _gone_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think you're not understanding and what's actually going on.

Normally, when you "go back" from a pushed view controller, the pushed view controller is popped *and destroyed*. Your pushed view controller is a NowPlayingViewController. It should be *destroyed* when you "go back" from it to the StationsViewController. Thus, when you show the NowPlayingViewController *again*, you would have to create a *new, different* NowPlayingViewController.

Okay, so far so good, provided you understand all of that. But in *your* case there is a further complication: you have a leak! Your old NowPlayingViewController is *not* being destroyed. Thus, when you "go back" to the StationsViewController and show the NowPlayingViewController for a second time, there are now *two* NowPlayingViewControllers — the new one that you see, and the old one that is leaking.

Okay, so your *logging* continues to show the *old* NowPlayingViewController, which is still observing and updating. But your *eyes* are seeing the *new* NowPlayingViewController, which is doing nothing. And that explains the phenomena you have described.

If this is right — and, from what you've said, I'm pretty sure it is — then you need to reorganize your architecture either so that you don't get this leak or so that when you show the NowPlayingViewController the second time you show the *same* NowPlayingViewController rather than creating a different one. (The first approach would be better.)

Comment: Hi matt, I really want to thank you for your answer! I understand what you said. I tried to debug my application view hierarchy in simulator and It seems that NowPlayingViewController is correctly destroyed. Here some images: on opening (https://www.dropbox.com/s/xam343xrt3abbwk/1st_time.png?dl=0), after coming back and returning (https://www.dropbox.com/s/5y9byuw9zujhide/2nd_time.png?dl=0).